# How can I disable Possible iteration over unexpected... inspection in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I am curious, how can I disable the following inspection of JavaScript in my IntellJ IDEA?

> Possible iteration over unexpected (custom / inherited) members, probably missing hasOwnProperty check

I tried to find the inspection in the settings as described here: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html
but I was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the inspection you're looking for is in the Inspections list under "JavaScript / General / Unfiltered for..in loop". You can uncheck it in the Inspections in Settings to disable that inspection.

[image: Settings / Inspections / JavaScript / General / Unfiltered for..in loop]

As with all inspections, make sure you understand what it's trying to tell you before just disabling it globally.